# Plotting 1 attribute of a shp file in R

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I'm trying to select & plot just one of these 9 attributes from my shape file, but nothing seems to work.
Could you help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyVMV.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For your next questions you should consider this advice: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you make a fully reproducible example so that fixers can run the code and be certain that they have resolved the issue.

Here is an example that you will have to modify for your own needs.

```
library(sf)
fname <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf") # read a shape file that comes with the sf package
nc <- st_read(fname)
plot(nc)  # plot all the data
```

[image]

```
plot(nc['AREA']) # plot one of the attributes
```

[image]

Comment: This is so, so, amazing!!! Thank you so much, it worked :D